# Android R8 release build CIRCULAR REFERENCE with AGP 8.0.2

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8

I can't build release apk file. Debug apk - created OK. It produces such an error, what I can add to proguard rules to fix this? Thanks.
On Android Gradle Plugin 7.4.2 - release is building OK, but on next versions: 8.0.2 or 8.2.0-alfa06 - it produces next error:

```
Missing class io.ktor.http.UrlEncodingOption (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.my_custom_package.proj_name.logger.internal.Factory.getAnonymousToken(kotlin.coroutines.Continuation))
                at com.android.tools.r8.utils.E2.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:29)
                at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.T1.b(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:11)
                at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.L.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:1735)
                at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.L.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:1442)
                at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:1279)
                at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:158)
                at com.android.tools.r8.R8.b(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:1)
                at com.android.tools.r8.utils.N0.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:23)
                at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:19)
                at com.android.tools.r8.R8.run(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:3)
                at com.android.builder.dexing.R8Tool.runR8(r8Tool.kt:324)
                at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$Companion.shrink(R8Task.kt:699)
                at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable.execute(R8Task.kt:773)
                at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
                at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
                at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
                at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
                at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
                at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
                at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
                at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
                at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
                at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$0(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:169)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
                at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
                at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
                at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
                at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
                at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
                at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:114)
                at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
                at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
                at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Missing class com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl (referenced from: java.lang.String com.google.crypto.tink.util.KeysDownloader.fetchAndCacheData())
```

Comment: If this is reported through AGP there should be an error message with a reference to a suggested addition to your keep rules. Most like it will be `-dontwarn io.ktor.http.UrlEncodingOption` which should silence the error. However, this could point to a missing (potentially optional) ktor dependency. If you have a simple sample app you can share please file a bug on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788, and we might be able to see where this missing class is referenced.